# Solang compiler fails when sending lamports within a loop (targeting Solana)

Tags: llvm, solidity, solana

I'm building a Solana program to manage payments to multiple accounts, however the compiler fails whenever a `.send()` call is made within a loop. For example, the following code compiles just fine:

```
function send( address[3] memory receivers ) external payable {
    require(payable(receivers[0]).send(uint64(5)), "Transaction failed");
}
```

But the following code throws an error:

```
function send( address[3] memory receivers ) external payable {
    for (uint i = 0; i < receivers.length; i++) {
      require(payable(receivers[i]).send(uint64(5)), "Transaction failed");
    }
}
```

`LLVM ERROR: Unsupported dynamic stack allocation`

I've also tried using `.transfer()` and `.call()`, all throw the same error. Is this behavior unsupported or is there a way I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Got the exact same issue, did you found any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue in solang v0.1.9. It should compile fine with solang latest main.

We should be release solang v0.1.10 shortly.

Answer (score 0):

@sean-young, hi!
got the same error on Solang 0.1.13, when tried to call

```
address pda =  create_program_address (["TokenAccountXXX", "seed"], _token );
```